Error creating bean 'securityFilterChain' in SecurityFilterChain: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception : Object already been built
I am trying to run my springboot application, but I am getting this error:
2024-10-28T12:59:40.730+03:00 ERROR 998 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/chama/chamaservice/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: This object has already been built
The error occurred after making significant updates to my packages in pom.xml, since they were extremely outdated.
This error comes from my security config class that looks like this:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true, // Enables @Secured annotation support
        jsr250Enabled = true, // Enables @RolesAllowed annotation support
        prePostEnabled = true // Enables @PreAuthorize and @PostAuthorize annotation support
)
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(http), userRepository);
        customAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/login");

        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable) // Disable CSRF
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)) // Stateless sessions
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(
                                "/api/login/**",
                                "/api/token/refresh/**",
                                "/api/users/save/**",
                                "/api/health/**",
                                "/api/daraja/c2b/validate/**",
                                "/api/daraja/c2b/confirm/**"
                        )
                        .permitAll() // Permit specific endpoints
                        .anyRequest().authenticated() // Require authentication for all other endpoints
                )
                .addFilter(customAuthenticationFilter) // Add authentication filter
                .addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); // Add authorization filter

        return http.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        return auth.build();
    }
}

The precise line throwing the error is return http.build();
I also have a CustomAuthenticationFilter class that is processed by the securityFilterChain, which looks like this:
@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Value("${security.jwt.secret}")
    private String jwtSecret = "x!A%D*G-KaPdSgVkYp3s6v9y/B?E(H+MbQeThWmZq4t7w!z%C&F)J@NcRfUjXn2r";

    public CustomAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String phoneNumber = request.getParameter("phoneNumber");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(phoneNumber, password);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ResourceNotFoundException {
        User user = (User) authResult.getPrincipal();

        com.chama.chamaservice.user.User principal = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(MessageUtil.ERROR_USER_NOTFOUND));

        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String accessToken = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .withClaim("userId", principal.getId())
                .withClaim("roles", user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .sign(algorithm);

        String refreshToken = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 300 * 60 * 1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .sign(algorithm);

        Map<String, String> userProfile = new HashMap<>();
        userProfile.put("access_token", accessToken);
        userProfile.put("refresh_token", refreshToken);

        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), userProfile);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<>();
        error.put("message", MessageUtil.UNSUCCESSFUL_AUTHENTICATION);

        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), error);
    }
}

Lastly, my pom.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.chama</groupId>
    <artifactId>chamaservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>chamaservice</name>
    <description>Chama Contribution Service</description>
    <properties>
        <start-class>com.chama.chamaservice.GroupServiceApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>17</java.version> <!-- Change from 11 to 17 -->
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version> <!-- or the latest version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.1.Final</version> <!-- or the version compatible with Jakarta -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.20.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version> <!-- Or the latest available version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version> <!-- Update to a version compatible with your Spring Boot version -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version> <!-- use the latest version -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.76.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.0.0-android</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.210</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.17.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <finalName>chamaservice-image</finalName>
                    <mainClass>com.chama.chamaservice.GroupServiceApplication</mainClass>
                    <layout>JAR</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I have checked and confirmed that http.build() has not been duplicated.
I also tried return http.getOrBuild(); instead of http.build();. It removed the error, but requestMatchers wouldn't work, citing 401 Unauthorised.
I have also checked other similar problems here on stack overflow, although some were quite similar, they did not address my situation.

your question is not clear enough, but some how I can give you some ways to try to debug this. First of all, change the SecurityFilterChain function name (this sound useless but this will help you check if did you accidentally created a filterchain with same name or not). Secondly, add this to your yml and look for the log, hope this will help logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
